# How to solve MobiLink server has encountered an error and the synchro in SUP android

Tags: android, synchronization, sup

I am developing android application using SUP. Application is registered on SCC and initially sync to SUP server but when I synchronize("test") particular synchronization group it will gives me below exception

```
TestDB.synchronize("Test");
p.setPersonalizationKey1(new BigDecimal("0"));
p.setPersonalizationKey2("");
p.save();
```

> ```
> Exception on synchronize method
>
>    W/System.err(5633): 
>    com.sybase.persistence.SynchronizeException:
>     com.ianywhere.ultralitejni12.implementation.JniException: UltraLiteJ Error
>    [-857]: Synchronization failed due to an error on the server: 
>    [-10244] The MobiLink server has encountered an error and the synchro
> ```

SUP Server Logs:

> [Test.server.TestDB]
>
> {"_op":"C","level":5,"code":500,"eisCode":"","message":"java.lang.IllegalStateException:column index 1 has no entry in columnIndexMap: {1=null, 2=2, 3=3, 4=4, 5=5, 6=6, 7=null, 8=null, 9=7, 10=null, 11=8, 12=9, 13=null, 14=11, 15=12, 16=13, 17=14, 18=15, 19=16, 20=17, 21=18, 22=19, 23=20, 24=21, 25=22, 26=23, 27=24, 28=25, 29=26, 30=27, 31=28, 32=29, 33=30, 34=39, 35=40, 36=41, 37=42, 38=43, 39=44, 40=45, 41=46, 42=47, 43=48, 44=49, 45=50, 46=51, 47=52, 48=53, 49=54, 50=55, 51=56, 52=57, 53=58, 54=59, 55=60, 56=61, 57=62, 58=63, 59=64, 60=65, 61=66, 62=67, 63=68, 64=69, 65=70, 66=71, 67=72, 68=73, 69=74, 70=75, 71=76, 72=77, 73=78, 74=79, 75=80, 76=81, 77=82, 78=83, 79=84, 80=85, 81=86, 82=87, 83=88, 84=89, 85=90, 86=91, 87=92, 88=93, 89=94, 90=95, 91=96, 92=97, 93=98, 94=99, 95=100, 96=101, 97=102, 98=103, 99=104, 100=105, 101=106, 102=107, 103=108, 104=109, 105=110, 106=111, 107=null, 108=113, 109=null, 110=114, 111=115, 112=124}; columnNameMap: {_ID=_ID, _Type=_Type, n","component":"TestDB","entityKey":null,"operation":"synchronize","requestId":null,"timestamp":"2014-04-30 11:31:33.625","messageId":0,"_rc":0}

Anyone know please help me resolve it.

Comment: This is an error during synchronization on the server side. Please provide the exact error message/ exception shown in mlsrv_err.log available on server folder that <install dir\Mobileplatform\servers\Unwiredserver\logs>

Comment: It seems that the server deployment has some issues. Please set the log level for MMS/ Dataservice to debug in SCC and save. Synchronize again to reproduce the error. Reset the log level back and save. And provide the complete exceptions in mlsrv_err.log + <servername>-server.log

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a mismatch between what SUP is expecting to receive from the backend and what is is actually receiving. Is looks like a column that is not nullable is receiving null value from the backend